# where microdata itemprop="url" tag coming from?

Tags: drupal, microdata, schema.org

I have microdata on my site

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
```

and I am getting the following in Rich Snippets for images on my page:

```
url:    https://example.com/artist/node/457
url:    https://example.com/artist/node/1137
```

My source code shows:

```
<meta itemref="md1 md3 md5 md6" />
<meta itemscope="" id="md3" itemref="md2" />
<meta itemref="md4 md7" />
<link href="node/457" itemprop="url" id="md6" />
<link href="node/1137" itemprop="url" id="md7" />
</div>
```

However, I don't think I hardcoded any `itemprop="url"` tags in my code. Where are they coming from? Does Rich Snippets put them in automatically? How do I remove these tags?

Comment: Just for info, I added a missing `<` in the first `meta` element (I guess you missed to copy&paste it, as you also omitted the opening `div`)

Comment: I didn't get you question. Can you provide more code or link to the page with markup? I see explicit itemprop="url" in your code snippet.

Comment: right, it is in my source code but I can't find where it is hard coded. (it is a drupal site) You can search the source code for them on page https://naiveartonline.com/painting/sailboats. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tags are from the [microdata](https://drupal.org/project/microdata) module even though I didn't have any of the fields filled in and I wasn't using it to display the microdata. I've disabled the module and they went away.